# How do I fill an array inside a while loop and get new scope each iteration?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

The problem is that I get only the last value comming from the Table. I think its because I am building the array while referencing its values to the same object, and it keeps changing. I know while loop doesnt create a new scope for each iteration which **IS** the problem.

**What's the best way to get a new scope for each iteration?**

**Code:**

```
    $namesArray= array();
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $nameAndCode->code = $row['country_code2'];
        $nameAndCode->name = $row['country_name'];           
        array_push($namesArray,$nameAndCode);


        } 
return $namesArray;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a new object on each iteration:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $nameAndCode = new stdClass;
    $nameAndCode->code = $row['country_code2'];
    $nameAndCode->name = $row['country_name'];           
    $namesArray[] = $nameAndCode;
}
```

Otherwise you're referencing the same object over and over, and just overwriting its values.

You also can do this with arrays if you don't require objects:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $nameAndCode = array();
    $nameAndCode['code'] = $row['country_code2'];
    $nameAndCode['name'] = $row['country_name'];           
    $namesArray[] = $nameAndCode;
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $namesArray[] = array( 
        'code' => $row['country_code2'],
        'name' => $row['country_name']
    );
}
```

Comment: whats the difference with array push?

Comment: You save the overhead of calling a function, which is the first note in array_push's documentation: `Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.`

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like:

```
$namesArray=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $nameAndCode=array("code"=>$row["country_code2"],
                     "name" => $row["country_name"]);
  array_push(&$namesArray,$nameAndCode);
};
```

I'd also try passing `$namesArray` by reference, like Viktor mentioned.
My code makes completely new array to push each iteration, which makes sure you dpn't overwrite stuff. Also, if you want to add stuff to an array by accessing it via its index you should use this:

```
// This is the right way
$someArray["foo"]="bar";
$someArray["baz"]="quux";
// This is wrong, it's only for OOP
$someArray->foo="bar";
$someArray->baz="quux";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
array_push(&$namesArray,$nameAndCode);
```

I think `array_push` requires a reference or pointer.

Is there a reason you aren't using `$namesArray[]`? Instead of the above:

```
$namesArray[] = $nameAndCode;
```

Comment: Avoid using '&' in function call. You will run into fatal errors with 5.4.

Comment: That's nice to know. I have never ever used `array_push()` either, I'm relying on `[]`.