# min and max value from array, gets always the same value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, max, min

I'm trying to get the Min and Max value from an Mysql array. But I always get the same value as output.

```
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM  `seriennummern` WHERE id = '$i'";
    $result1 = $mysqli->query($query1);
    $countSN = $result1->num_rows;
    while($row = $result1->fetch_array())
    {
        $max = (max(array($row['Seriennummer'])));
        $min = (min(array($row['Seriennummer'])));
        print_r(array($row['Seriennummer']));

    }
```

The output from print_r is

```
Array ( [0] => 53928 ) Array ( [0] => 56945 ) Array ( [0] => 58055 ) Array ( [0] => 59149 ) Array ( [0] => 70518 ) Array ( [0] => 72020 ) Array ( [0] => 71198 ) Array ( [0] => 51161 ) Array ( [0] => 56945 ) Array ( [0] => 70665 )
```

And I got as value the last value from array 70665.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727746/how-do-i-fill-an-array-inside-a-while-loop-and-get-new-scope-each-iteration

Comment: If using a loop approach (and I'm not sure that you should), you could simply compare the current value with the previous value, and take the higher (and lower) of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `MIN and MAX` query

```
SELECT MIN(Seriennummer) AS Min_Seriennummer, MAX(Seriennummer) AS Max_Seriennummer 
FROM  `seriennummern` WHERE GeraeteID = '$i'
```

And you get min and max value

```
$result1 = $mysqli->query($query1);
$countSN = $result1->num_rows;
while ($row = $result1->fetch_array()) {
    echo $min = $row['Min_Seriennummer'];
    echo $max = $row['Max_Seriennummer'];
}
```

Your code is open for sql injection check [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496) to prevent it